# Instagram not showing old images using hastag

Tags: jquery, ajax, instagram, instagram-api

I have Instagram pulling in photos using a hashtag, there should be 9-10 photos it is pulling in one photo of the 10, which is a recent photo I just added.

Anyone know what's going on here?
Below is a link to the codepen

https://codepen.io/loyer807/pen/rQZrGL

```
var token = '4113764207.afa39af.906d00fc3284485487847bcc7c80be88',
hashtag='AlopexIdOffice', // hashtag without # symbol
num_photos = 4;

$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + hashtag + '/media/recent',
dataType: 'jsonp',
type: 'GET',
data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    for(x in data.data){
        $('ul').append('<li><img 
src="'+data.data[x].images.standard_resolution.url+'"></li>');  
    }
},
error: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the instagram api works but generally you don't want to share the token with others.